# Peak load upgrade and downgrade SQL Server 2017 Standard <-> SQL Server 2017 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We are currently running on SQL Server 2017 standard edition and for higher traffic weekends like Mothers day we want to go on SQL Server 2017 enterprise version and during non peak hours we want to come back on Standard. We run on AWS EC2 images of respective versions. My question is

1. Can we just take the backup of 2017 standard and restore on 2017 enterprise? I mean do we have to do an in place upgrade and not a backup and restore
2. Similarly can we do a restore from 2017 enterprise to 2017 standard during non peak hours? I mean it is mandatory to do an in place downgrade

We tried the backup restore option and running into memory issues

What is the best approach?

Comment: This is a super strange pattern - why do you think changing the edition of the engine you're using will increase performance?

Comment: to use more memory ?

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64 max memory for standard is 128GB - if they're hitting a bottleneck on memory I'd expect they have enough cash for Enterprise full stop. That's why this is confusing.

Comment: George, Stephen, yes you guys are correct. we go to enterprise so that we can set higher max memory to cater to higher load. Well i cant comment on how much cash our client has :) , they want us to come back to Standard full stop :)

Comment: Here is the chronology 
1. Went from Standard to Enterprise , ran for 6 hours . Ran into memory issues
2. Restored the DB back from Enterprise to Standard, still ran into memory issues. Upgraded the box to 8x EC2 large. After which running fine
3. But we want to remain on 4xLarge due to higher cost of 8x

Basically we want to find what is causing memory issues when we upgrade or downgrade

@George.Palacios

Comment: @MuzammilAhmed what do you mean "memory issues" - could you add any error messages etc you got?

Comment: @MuzammilAhmed I'm with George. How do you know you were having **Memory Issues**?...what information did you use to determine this? Based on your chronology it sounds like going from Standard to Enterprise Edition didn't solve your problem. It sounds like it was only solved when you chose an instance that provides roughly double the resources, including **CPU**, which I wouldn't doubt is what actually made more of an impact with your issue. Also knowing exactly which category of instances you're referring to would be helpful (e.g. Compute Optimized vs Storage Optimized vs Memory Optimized?).

Comment: what we believe is that when we came back from Enterprise to Standard( step 2 above) , we might have carried some settings from Enterprise to Standard which is what might have caused the issue. Because prior to all this we were running fine on Standard on a 4x box . @George.Palacios

Comment: 2021-04-28 06:00:00.57 Server      Error: 701, Severity: 17, State: 226.
2021-04-28 06:00:00.57 Server      There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
2021-04-28 06:00:00.57 Logon       Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 14.
2021-04-28 06:00:00.57 Logon       SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x80090300, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The operating system error code indicates the cause of failure. Not enough memory is available to complete ..

Comment: @MuzammilAhmed my advice to you is take that error message and post a brand new question - you are not addressing the route cause of the issue otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Answers to your questions below, this doesn´t necessarily mean that I think it is a good idea, it seems quite a high risk approach to me.

1. Yes restoring a standard edition db to enterprise edition just works as long as it is not on a later version than the destination server.
2. Restoring an enterprise edition to a standard edition works AS LONG AS you have not started to use enterprise features

you can query sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features

see
https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/enterprise-edition-features/

Comment: ... and note that this DMV still show some features as "enterprise only" even they nowadays are available on Standard Edition as of SQL Server 2016 (things such as compression, partitioning, columnstore indexes etc).

Comment: @stephenmorris , i discussed the aspect of DB using the Enterprise features with my DBA, and for that he said that it is not possible that the DB may be using the Enterprise features because the DB is set to use 2008 compatibility level which is 100

Comment: Well the database itself is not going to spontaneously implement enterprise features but I can think of a few that are present even in 2008